# React Native Invariant Violation: View config not found for name img

Tags: reactjs, react-native

When I run react-native run-android I get an Invariant Violation which tells me "to view config not found or name navigation". And then all the sites where this violation happens. Help please thanks.

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { Card } from "shards-react";
class User extends React.Component {
  render() {
     const { name, avatar, email, isLoading } = this.props;
     const userDetails = (
      <div>
        <img
          className="img-thumbnail rounded-circle mx-auto mb-2 shadow-sm"
          src={avatar}
          alt={name}
          style={{ width: "100px", height: "100px" }}
         />
        <h4 className="mb-0">{name}</h4>
        <span className="text-muted">{email}</span>
      </div>
    );
    const loadingMessage = <span className="d-flex m-auto">Loading... 
 </span>;
    return (
      <Card
        className="mx-auto mt-4 text-center p-5"
        style={{ maxWidth: "300px", minHeight: "250px" }}
      >
        {isLoading ? loadingMessage : userDetails}
      </Card>
    );
  }
}
User.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string,
  avatar: PropTypes.string,
  email: PropTypes.string,
  isLoading: PropTypes.bool
};
export default User;
```

[image: image 1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use DOM elements (div, img, h4, span,...) inside a React Native application. React Native uses Native iOS or Android elements to communicate with.

Check out the [React Native docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/view) for more details.